# Pause main flow and then continue where it was left in BPMN

Tags: camunda, bpmn, bpmn.io

I'm having trouble modeling a process in BPMN. Basically I have a subprocess running inside a main flow, then every certain time there are report meetings (lets say a subprocess) that "pauses" the current subprocess, and once it is finished the initial subprocess should continue where it was left.

Is there any way to model this?
[In this case, initial subprocess goes Task 1 -> Task 2 -> Task 3, and every certain time a different subprocess takes place, I need that f.e if Task 1 was running when secondary subprocess takes place, once it is finished, first subprocess continues at Task 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXX0a.png)

Thanks

I tried using non-interrupting time event, but the problem is that it makes the interrupting subprocess run in parallel, when really I need the initial subprocess to be "on hold" until the other one is completed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is no way to suspend and resume a sub process. A task on the other hand is atomic. Since the process model doesn't contain anything about the state of an atomic task, it can only be aborted. So a way to deal with this situation is to abort each of the three tasks, then call the report meeting subprocess and return to the aborted task to restart it. [image]

This looks complicated, but if you really want to stop people from working on a task while they are in a report meeting, this is how you can achieve this. I don't know, if this is necessary. If people can multitask, they can do both. If they can't multitask, the work is automatically suspended, while they are in the report meeting.